# is_file and zend framework routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a problem when checking if a file exists in zend framework 2:

When checking:

```
is_file("/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/my_viena/panel/public/img/familias/101.jpg")
```

which is the absolute route in my computer, it returns true.

When checking:

```
is_file($this->basePath()."/img/familias/101.jpg")
```

which is the route from the module, it returns false.

If I make:

```
echo "<img src='".$this->basePath()."/img/familias/101.jpg'>";
```

the browser shows de image correctly.

What is wrong in my code? I want to check if the file exists with the relative route.

Comment: have u tried only "public/img/familias/101.jpg"? My same problem was solved using this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: THanks rack_nilesh, your suggestion works perfectly.

Comment: Hi guessimtoolate, I want to do that to check if a file exists before offer the option to upload and to avoid broken links when displaying images

Comment: Hi rack_niles, I'm new on stack overflow, Should I rate your answer in some way?

Comment: `$this->basePath()` return the base url for your site witch is usually `/`, unless you r in a sub folder and not the domains root public folder then it will return `/subfolder/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one situation `$this->basePath()` will return and empty string.
And when checking if your file exists it will search for the absolute path `/img/familias/101.jpg`

`echo "<img src='".$this->basePath()."/img/familias/101.jpg'>";` will show the image 
because it will load something like this www.yoursite.com/img/familias/101.jpg

`public/img/familias/101.jpg` works because everything in zf2 is realtive to the `public` folder (I think)

side note
don't use echo for creating your tags